# General error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

when I search any product in top search I get error in Magento.I searched lot in stack over flow and  Magento stack exchange but all that solution is not worked in my case.

for ex : if I search "dell laptop" and hit enter it go to error page and error is below.

> a:5:{i:0;s:494:"
>       SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query, query was:
>       INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result`
>       SELECT 2992 AS `query_id`, `s`.`product_id`,
>       MATCH (s.data_index) AGAINST (:query IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS `relevance`
>       FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s`INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = s.product_id
>       WHERE (s.store_id = 1) AND (MATCH (s.data_index) AGAINST (:query IN BOOLEAN MODE)) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `relevance` =
>   VALUES(`relevance`)
>       ";i:1;s:4001:"`

I also truncate all log tables but it's also not working in my case.

so if you guys have any other solution please share with me.

Comment: build index and try search for product..

Comment: @Charlie I tried that too any other solution.

Comment: check local.xml file and make sure your database confugrations are correct. than clear `var/cache` floder and than try

Comment: @Charlie I have tried all ordinary solution that are available on net and I have tried above solution too. one more thing I am indexing using SSH so all indexing are reindex perfectly but  "Catalog Search Index" is not reindexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue at my end successfully :)

1. First you delete locks folder under var directory: var/locks
2. make sure 777 permission is var/locks and all files under locks directory.
3. Take a backup of your database & delete catalog_product_flat_1, catalog_product_flat_2 or if there is another one.
4. execute following code:

**`php indexer.php --reindex catalogsearch_fulltext`**
This will reindex your Catalog Search Index or if you want to update all of the indexes run:

**`php indexer.php reindexall`**

Comment: try this and tell me the result

Comment: you mean var/locks or var/log folder?? because there is var/log folder not var/locks.

Comment: check it should be there.. https://www.sonassi.com/blog/magento-kb/catalog-search-index-refresh-running-slow-or-haltingfreezing check that link you will understand your problem

Comment: obviously the answer is here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-lost-connection.html